# Can we force a sharepoint modern page to auto refresh each N minutes

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, modern-pages

We have a modern sharepoint page, and we have adding many lists' views to it using the List modern web part:-

[image]

but we have noted that any modifications we make to the underlying lists (such as add, edit, delete items) will not be pushed inside the list modern web parts... so as a fix can we force the modern page to auto-refresh each N minutes?

Thanks

Comment: do you care if the *entire page* is refreshed or do you require that only the list webpart gets refreshed?  Refreshing the entire page will be easier and more reliable to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Embed web part** instead of **List web part**.

1. On the Embed web part panel, enter the url of list in the **Website address or embed code box**.

- https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/site_name/Lists/list_name/AllItems.aspx
  [image]

[image]

2. **Republish** page
3. When you making to the underlying lists (such as add, edit, delete items), the **Embed web part** will update automatically.

------------------------------ **Updated Answer** ---------------------------

**Please the following steps:**

First, deploy the **Modern Script Editor Webpart** in the SharePoint Online environment.

More information, Please refer to this article:

- [Add The Script Editor Webpart back to SharePoint Modern Experience](https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4)

[image]

Then, add the **Modern Script Editor Webpart** to your SharePoint Online Page.

[image]

[image]

**Paste the below code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 
function refreshPage(){
location.reload();
}
setTimeout(refreshPage, 6000);
 
</script>
```

[image]

Finally, **Publish/Republish** page.

Comment: the Embed works quite different than the List where on the List web part you have the option to hide the command bar + control the number of items to be shown... so that why i did not use the Embed, as i do not want the command bar to be shown inside the modern page..

Comment: Hi, John. I have updated my answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!